DOMA Abbreviation
I am attempting to translate Libavius' Alchymia. My Latin is pretty rusty and it will be a slow going process. The title page has the Hebrew Jehovah (הוה') and four letters DOMA which I am assuming is an acronym in Latin. DOM can mean Deo Optimo Maximo. I consulted with ChatGPT (which I trust very little) which said the addition of the A could be for "Deo Optimo Maximo Auctoritate" or "Deo Optimo Maximo Altissimo." These seemed plausible to me but I thought I would double check here to see if anyone knew for sure.

Are there other translations or books about alchemy you can consult? I would assume it's part of alchemical tradition rather than a normal Latin abbreviation, and there are hundreds of words in Latin beginning with A that could fit.

The Wiki article on Latin abbreviations says it's aeterno ('eternal'), though no source is given.
I did find this website which purports to explain the abbreviation on another book. This book also has the tetragrammaton.
This 19th-century book of Latin abbreviations also gives aeterno, but also auxilio and auspiciis, suggesting that there might not be one single word that everyone had in mind when using the abbreviation.
